# Python, nested loops print on one line, multiple copies

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very new to python so please excuse!

question is...to make an output look like

```
1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5

1 2 3 4 5
```

I am using user input for the limit and the number of copies ( in this example 5 and 3), so  I have done this;

```
limit = int(input("Select upper limit"))
copies = int(input("Select number of copies"))


def output(limit):
    for i in range(copies):
        for x in range(limit):
            print (x + 1, end=" ")


output(limit)
```

However the answer shows up as `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5`. I know it's because of the `end=" "` but not sure how to get around it! Any help appreciated

Comment: BTW: There's an issue with your code concerning the scope of variables. The function `output` receives a parameter `limit`, which the second "parameter" `copies` is just a global variable. I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print new line explicitly for every loop:

```
def output(copies, limit):
    for i in range(copies):
        for x in range(limit):
            print (x + 1, end=" ")
        print()  # <----
        # print()  # Add this if you want an empty line

output(copies, limit)
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer (by adding a comment in the code) according to you.

Answer (score 3):

You got the part with the ranges correctly, but there's one thing you missed, you can specify a starting number:

```
v0 = range(1, limit + 1)
```

In order to convert a number to a string, use the `str()` function:

```
v1 = (str(x) for x in v0)
```

In order to put a space between adjacent numbers, use the string's `join()` memberfunction:

```
v2 = ' '.join(v1)
```

Then, you could either add the linebreaks yourself:

```
v3 = (v2 + '\n') * copies
print(v3, end='')
```

Alternatively in this form:

```
v3 = '\n'.join(v2 for i in range(copies))
print(v3)
```

Or you just print the same line multiple times in a plain loop:

```
for i in range(copies):
    print(v2)
```

BTW: Note that `v0` and `v1` are generators, so joining them into a string `v2` will change their internal state, so you can't simply repeat that and get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

```
limit = int(input("Select upper limit"))
copies = int(input("Select number of copies"))

def output(limit):
    for i in range(copies):
        if (i!=0):
            print()
            print()
        for x in range(limit):
            print (x + 1, end="")

output(limit)
```

Comment: The question is tagged `python-3.x`.

Comment: It still has the end-of-line character at the beginning of all but the first line and is badly indented.

Comment: Edited it now. Thank you for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little modification to your code:

```
def output(limit):
    for i in range(copies):
        for x in range(limit):
            print(x + 1, end=' ')
        print()
```